# Hide an amp-iframe when content of iframe doesn't load

Tags: javascript, iframe, amp-html

I am wondering if there is any way to hide an AMP iframe in the case that the content inside the iframe does not load? 
I have tried setting height to 0px (using postMessage from inside the iframe when content fails), but AMP does not allow this and I am having problems finding a way around this.

I would prefer a fix that allows me to hide it from within the iframe, but I don't think this is actually possible, so a simple solution to hide it from the outside page would also be great at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

AMP Does't allow you to change much things dynamically, Because it may affect the user experience and page load. AMP is all about user first experience 

 So Unfortunately you don't have anyway to do it right now...!